# Google translate API works on localhost but on my EC2 ubuntu

Tags: localhost, google-translate

This my first time ever interacting with an API so I apologize in advance if my question is trivial.

I was able to successfully interact with google's API on my localhost, but I ran into several problems when moving from a localhost to an EC2 using ubuntu as my OS. For starters, I couldn't open port 443, and now I have finally opened that port. I am now being greeting with this

```
error message:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

The error is ambiguous and so is the answer Google provided for it(Google claims my output might be invalid,but if that was true then it wouldn't work on my localhost). My header looks like this:

```
target:hi
Language:60
```

I am unsure on how to resolve this and would greatly appreciate any benevolent soul help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your request URL without the key?

Comment: Your question lead me to the correct answer. When I migrated from my localhost to an EC2, I had a capitalization error in my database.  The error was obvious was I looked at the url.  How do I give you credit?

Comment: How do I close this?